# Uniform Circular Motion Confusion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Having some problems when calculating this problem:

A fly lands on an old record player, while a 7'' O.D. 45 RPM record is playing. If the fly lands on the edge of the record, determine the records period of rotation.

I do not understand how to calculate (T) tau.

w = (2*PI*R)(#cycles/sec) = (2*PI*V)

T = 1/V

R is 7.0 in (or 0.18 meters)
45 RPM is 4.72 radians/second

Therefore to find w:

w = (2*PI)(0.18m)(4.72rad/s) = 5.33 meters*radians/second

Please notice that I have meters * radians when this should be only radians and seconds.

I am just looking to calculate Tau (T)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused as to why the $7$ inches and the fly landing on the very edge of the record is relevant. Period is simply the time it takes for the record to go through one complete revolution. Because the record spins with a frequency of $45rpm$ we can find period directly by:
$$ T = {1 \over f} = {1 \over 45 {rev \over min}} = .022min$$

Equivalently, by multiplying by $60$ you can convert to seconds:
$$ .022min*{60sec \over 1min} = 1.3sec$$

Comment: Thanks! The speed is, therefore: v=2*PI*R/T = 0.85m/s? Or is it v=PI*R/T

Comment: Yes that equation is correct but I believe when it says 7 inch record it means 7 inches in diameter. So your radius would be 3.5 inches. Using that I get .43m/s.

Comment: No, v = 2*pi*r/T is correct